# How to add observations "n" to each group in ggplot2 manually?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a bar graph in which I would like to add n = 12, n = 15 below s1 and s2 or I would like to add n = 12, n= 15 above the error bar or inside the bar graph with particular font, Arial and size 12. Is there anyway I can add manually and set the position according my preference? Please help. This is an example code:

```
survey <- data.frame(group=rep(c("TR", "PS"),each=1),
                 sample=rep(c("s1", "s2"),1),
                 values=c(500,50 ),
                 se=c(1,2))



library(ggplot2)
ggplot(survey, aes(x=sample, y=values, fill=group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=values - se, ymax=values + se),
            position=position_dodge(width = 0.2),width=0.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add the needed data to `survey`.  Then use `geom_text` to produce the text over the bars (or if you want it under the bars use `geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = c("n = 12", "n = 15")), vjust = 1)` instead.  To add text below the X axis labels we modify the `x` aesthetic in the ggplot call.

```
library(ggplot2)

survey$label = c("n = 12", "n = 15")
survey <- transform(survey, labelx = paste(sample, "\n", label))

ggplot(survey, aes(x=labelx, y = values, fill=group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=values - se, ymax=values + se),
            position=position_dodge(width = 0.2),width=0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), vjust = -1)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much. I am also looking to add n = 12 and n = 15, below s1 and s2 with a particular font of Arial and 12. When I adjust vjust, n=15 is disappearing. How can I fix this.

Comment: Probably better to use the y aesthetic to position the labels in the middle of the bar, or set y directly if you want them below the bars, rather than messing with `vjust`. For example: `geom_text(aes(label =  c("n = 12", "n = 15"), y=0.5*values))` or `geom_text(aes(label =  c("n = 12", "n = 15")), y=-10)`.

Comment: Have shown it over the bars, under the bars and under the labels in the revised version.